# How Can I make a list automatically with Json for my Angular project?

Tags: html, css, json, angular, typescript

My json is :

```
{
    "exp": [
        {
            "first": "bla",
            "second": "blabla",
            "desp": [
                {
                    "line": "Instant Apzel bestseller"
                },
                {
                    "line": "Translated into 18 languages"
                },
                {
                    "line": "Most Recommended Book of the year."
                },
                {
                    "line": "A neglected project, widely dismissed, its champion written off as unhinged."
                },
                {
                    "line": "Yields a negative result in an experiment because of a flaw in the design of the experiment"
                },
                {
                    "line": "An Amazon, Bloomberg, Financial Times, Forbes, Inc., Newsweek, Strategy + Business, Teech Crunch, Washinton Post Best Business Book oof the year"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

in html with angular how can I call this json data with easyly?
Cause now I do like that;

```
<p>{{item.description.desSummary}}</p>
<ul class="desc-content">
  <li>{{item.description.desList.lineMono}}</li>
  <li>{{item.description.desList.lineDi}}</li>
  <li>{{item.description.desList.lineTri}}</li>
  <li>{{item.description.desList.lineTetra}}</li>
  <li>{{item.description.desList.linePenta}}</li>
  <li>{{item.description.desList.lineHexa}}</li>
</ul>
```

and json like that:

```
"desList": {
    "lineMono": "Instant Apzel bestseller",
    "lineDi": "Translated into 18 languages",
    "lineTri": "Most Recommended Book of the year.",
    "lineTetra": "A neglected project, widely dismissed, its champion written off as unhinged.",
    "linePenta": "Yields a negative result in an experiment because of a flaw in the design of the experiment",
    "lineHexa": "An Amazon, Bloomberg, Financial Times, Forbes, Inc., Newsweek, Strategy + Business, Teech Crunch, Washinton Post Best Business Book oof the year"
}
```

I want to do that with just one code block like this:

```
 > <div *ngFor=let item of exp>
 > <ul><li>{{item.desp.line}}<li/><ul/>
 > <div/>
```

How can I do like that. I tryed but there is some problems.

Comment: create an object with multiple arrays like 
`exp = [
{},
{}
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way -

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data.exp" class="item">
  <p class="first">{{ item.first }}</p>
  <p class="second">{{ item.second }}</p>
  <div class="desp-list" *ngFor="let desp of item.desp">
    <p class="desp-item">{{ desp.line }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ednxpy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with your data.

**Edit:** See a working example with data from a json file, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cjq5un?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks but ur solution is in typescript type. My datas in Json file .jason not .ts.

Comment: @omerf.bn I have added one more example with data from a json file. Let me know if you face any other issues.